# Where is the extra space coming from? (XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm generating hyperlinks with XSLT and I keep getting extra spaces at the end of the linked words.

My XML looks like this:

```
The last word needs to be a <url id="1">link</url>.
```

The link is concatenated, using the @id. Here's my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="//url">
    <a href="../mainsite.html{@id}"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></a>
</xsl:template>
```

For some reason, this generates a link on the word 'link', but it adds a space after it, even though there is no space between the url tags.

If I switch out the xsl:copy-of for a plain string the problem goes away. eg:

```
<xsl:template match="//url">
    <a href="../mainsite.html{@id}">string</a>
</xsl:template>
```

Where on earth is the extra space coming from? It's driving me mad, because any link that's followed by punctuation looks screwy. Where should I be looking at to track down the problem?

Thank you so much to anyone who can help.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a minimal example of input XML, conversion XSLT and output HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:template match="//url">
>     <a href="../mainsite.html{@id}"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></a>
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> For some reason, this generates a link on the word 'link', but it adds
>   a space after it

The problem is that you are using:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

where you should be using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

And since your stylesheet is evidently set to indent the output, you end up with:

```
The last word needs to be a <a href="../mainsite.html1">
      <url id="1">link</url>
   </a>
```

The browser then ignores the non-HTML tags and renders the line breaks as spaces.

Comment: Thank you! I need to use copy-of as there are child nodes that I don't want stripped out. But no matter what I did I couldn't work out where that whitespace was coming from. I never thought of the indent setting. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Seoirse "*there are child nodes that I don't want stripped out*" Then you probably want to use `xsl:apply-templates`. Post a more complete example to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

The normalize-space property will remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped to fix the problem in combination with the answers below that helped explain where it was coming from. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It could be adding a line break at the end of the value.  Normal behavior for xsl:copy-of is to add an ending line break which could present itself as an extra space.

Comment: "*Normal behavior for xsl:copy-of is to add an ending line break*" No, such line break would be added by `<xsl:output ... indent="yes"/>`.